# Function to change font size in js. how to add zooming limit?

Tags: javascript

I have function:

```
    function changeFontSize(points) {
        var e = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(e);
        var size = style.getPropertyValue('font-size');
        size = size.replace("px", "");
        size = size * 1;
        size = size + points;
        //if(size <= 0 && size  <= 3){
            e.style.fontSize = size + "px";
            localStorage.setItem("size", size);
        //}
    }

    function saveFontSize() {
        var size = localStorage.getItem("size");
        if (size !== null) {
            var e = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
            e.style.fontSize = size + "px", '!important';
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", saveFontSize);



<a href="#" onclick="changeFontSize(1);">plus</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeFontSize(-1);">minus</a>
```

The above code works correctly.
The above function enlarges and reduces the font size on my website.

I need to limit the function of this function to a maximum of 3 times the size of the font. The font size reduction (lower font size) can not be smaller than its original (original size).

How to do it?
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the initial font size and then make use of [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```
body.style.fontSize = Math.max(
  initialBodyFontSize, 
  Math.min(
    initialBodyFontSize * 3, 
    getBodyFontSize() + points
  )
) + 'px';
```

Demo (without the loading/saving through `localStorage` part, since it's not possible here):

```js
{
  var body = document.querySelector('body');
  var initialBodyFontSize;
  
  // Note: this supposes the body's font size is expressed in px
  function getBodyFontSize() { 
    return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(body).getPropertyValue('font-size'));
  }

  function changeBodyFontSize(points) {
    body.style.fontSize = Math.max(
      initialBodyFontSize, 
      Math.min(
        initialBodyFontSize * 3, 
        getBodyFontSize() + points
      )
    ) + 'px';
    console.log(body.style.fontSize);
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    initialBodyFontSize = getBodyFontSize();
  });
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="changeBodyFontSize(1);">plus</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeBodyFontSize(-1);">minus</a>
```

Also note that you should generally avoid `onclick` and similar attributes, and prefer `addEventListener` JS calls on the associated DOM elements instead.